# Print statement does not concatenate strings and variables in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, printing, concatenation

Why the following code returns an exception in the last line?

```
print(m)

print(b)

print(r)

print(p)

print(se)

print("m: " + m + "\n" + "b: " + b + "\n" +  "r: " + r + "\n" +  "p " + p + "\n" +  "se " + se)

1516.13788561
-5731.63903831
0.858729519032
4.15127287882e-05
250.925294078
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-7e2d88a4b5a8> in <module>()
      9 print(se)
     10 
---> 11 print("m: " + m + "\n" + "b: " + b + "\n" +  "r: " + r + "\n" +  "p " + p + "\n" +  "se " + se)

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: I think print command in python only works with strings, as the variables are of type floats you will have to cast them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the variables as strings for the print function.

```
print("m: " + str(m) + "\n" + "b: " + str(b) + "\n" +  "r: " + str(r) + "\n" +  "p " + str(p) + "\n" +  "se " + str(se))
```